# How to prevent PHP from writing to a config file with permissions 644?

Tags: php, file-permissions

An application I've installed is reporting that it's able to write to the config file, and that I should change the permissions to either 644 or 444. The permissions are currently 644. The file is owned by the same user that owns all the web files (the same user I use for FTP and SSH) who is NOT the root user, so if I make the permissions 444 I won't be able to modify the file in any way unless I get root access. (It's not my server so I would have to ask for that.) My question is, how is PHP able to write to the file if 644 means that only the owner can write to it? I've heard of things like suPHP that enable you to run PHP with the same permissions as a designated user. I ran "php -i" at the command line and searched for "suPHP", but found nothing. Here is more or less the complete dump:

```
PHP Version => 5.4.22

System => Linux 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 31 17:20:51 UTC 2014 x86_64
Build Date => Dec  2 2013 17:53:19
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.22

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => On => On
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => error_log => error_log
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 32759 => 32759
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => Off => Off
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php => .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 10M => 10M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => no value => no value
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => On => On
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 50M => 50M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.24.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.0
ZLib Version => 1.2.3

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2013.8
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => America/Denver

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => America/Denver => America/Denver

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.0
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 6496ccdb6a0a4792ced7f000203981dd4afe3657 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.3.11
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.49
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.12

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

imap

IMAP c-Client Version => 2007f
SSL Support => enabled
Kerberos Support => enabled

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.0
libXML Loaded Version => 20900
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 4.7.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mcrypt

mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
Version => 2.5.8
Api No => 20021217
Supported ciphers => cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes 
Supported modes => cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => 5.5.37
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlclient 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 5.5.37
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API header version => 5.5.32
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

mysqlnd

mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $
Compression => supported
SSL => supported
Command buffer size => 4096
Read buffer size => 32768
Read timeout => 31536000
Collecting statistics => Yes
Collecting memory statistics => No
Tracing => n/a
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,example,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
API Extensions => pdo_mysql

mysqlnd statistics =>  
bytes_sent => 0
bytes_received => 0
packets_sent => 0
packets_received => 0
protocol_overhead_in => 0
protocol_overhead_out => 0
bytes_received_ok_packet => 0
bytes_received_eof_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet => 0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet => 0
bytes_received_change_user_packet => 0
packets_sent_command => 0
packets_received_ok => 0
packets_received_eof => 0
packets_received_rset_header => 0
packets_received_rset_field_meta => 0
packets_received_rset_row => 0
packets_received_prepare_response => 0
packets_received_change_user => 0
result_set_queries => 0
non_result_set_queries => 0
no_index_used => 0
bad_index_used => 0
slow_queries => 0
buffered_sets => 0
unbuffered_sets => 0
ps_buffered_sets => 0
ps_unbuffered_sets => 0
flushed_normal_sets => 0
flushed_ps_sets => 0
ps_prepared_never_executed => 0
ps_prepared_once_executed => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor => 0
rows_affected_normal => 0
rows_affected_ps => 0
rows_skipped_normal => 0
rows_skipped_ps => 0
copy_on_write_saved => 0
copy_on_write_performed => 0
command_buffer_too_small => 0
connect_success => 0
connect_failure => 0
connection_reused => 0
reconnect => 0
pconnect_success => 0
active_connections => 0
active_persistent_connections => 0
explicit_close => 0
implicit_close => 0
disconnect_close => 0
in_middle_of_command_close => 0
explicit_free_result => 0
implicit_free_result => 0
explicit_stmt_close => 0
implicit_stmt_close => 0
mem_emalloc_count => 0
mem_emalloc_amount => 0
mem_ecalloc_count => 0
mem_ecalloc_amount => 0
mem_erealloc_count => 0
mem_erealloc_amount => 0
mem_efree_count => 0
mem_efree_amount => 0
mem_malloc_count => 0
mem_malloc_amount => 0
mem_calloc_count => 0
mem_calloc_amount => 0
mem_realloc_count => 0
mem_realloc_amount => 0
mem_free_count => 0
mem_free_amount => 0
mem_estrndup_count => 0
mem_strndup_count => 0
mem_estndup_count => 0
mem_strdup_count => 0
proto_text_fetched_null => 0
proto_text_fetched_bit => 0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_text_fetched_short => 0
proto_text_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_text_fetched_int => 0
proto_text_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_text_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_text_fetched_float => 0
proto_text_fetched_double => 0
proto_text_fetched_date => 0
proto_text_fetched_year => 0
proto_text_fetched_time => 0
proto_text_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_text_fetched_string => 0
proto_text_fetched_blob => 0
proto_text_fetched_enum => 0
proto_text_fetched_set => 0
proto_text_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_text_fetched_other => 0
proto_binary_fetched_null => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bit => 0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_short => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_binary_fetched_float => 0
proto_binary_fetched_double => 0
proto_binary_fetched_date => 0
proto_binary_fetched_year => 0
proto_binary_fetched_time => 0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_binary_fetched_string => 0
proto_binary_fetched_blob => 0
proto_binary_fetched_enum => 0
proto_binary_fetched_set => 0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_binary_fetched_other => 0
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_quit => 0
com_init_db => 0
com_query => 0
com_field_list => 0
com_create_db => 0
com_drop_db => 0
com_refresh => 0
com_shutdown => 0
com_statistics => 0
com_process_info => 0
com_connect => 0
com_process_kill => 0
com_debug => 0
com_ping => 0
com_time => 0
com_delayed_insert => 0
com_change_user => 0
com_binlog_dump => 0
com_table_dump => 0
com_connect_out => 0
com_register_slave => 0
com_stmt_prepare => 0
com_stmt_execute => 0
com_stmt_send_long_data => 0
com_stmt_close => 0
com_stmt_reset => 0
com_stmt_set_option => 0
com_stmt_fetch => 0
com_deamon => 0
bytes_received_real_data_normal => 0
bytes_received_real_data_ps => 0

example statistics =>  
stat1 => 0
stat2 => 0

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.21 2011-12-12

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.7.7.1

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: c85687ef5cec51a63c41cffb9ec3972cb8c3f7f3 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => disabled (install pecl/bz2)
OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: 32db6705f5b617967a546be3114e178a4138c1ca $

pspell

PSpell Support => enabled

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: c4a7c554f00da47fe9cff384d18c532a1a959dff $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary wddx 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => no value => no value
session.entropy_length => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.hash_bits_per_character => 4 => 4
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /tmp => /tmp
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 2358f2be6570ab413d0ead3a931a5365adf94af9 $
Schema support => enabled

soap

Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7
SQLite Library => 3.7.7.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

tidy

Tidy support => enabled
libTidy Release => 25 March 2009
Extension Version => 2.0 ($Id$)

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
tidy.clean_output => 0 => 0
tidy.default_config => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
EXPAT Version => expat_2.0.1

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlrpc

core library version => xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version => 0.51
author => Dan Libby
homepage => http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by => Epinions.com

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.27
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.0
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.27

Zend Guard Loader

Zend Guard Loader => enabled
License Path =>  
Obfuscation level => 0

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: 1f435bbb002ed00b47964fbd6e3b1cea9b161c07 $
Zip version => 1.11.0
Libzip version => 0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.3
Linked Version => 1.2.3

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name
ionCube Loader

Environment

Variable => Value
TERM => xterm-256color
SHELL => /bin/bash
HISTSIZE => 1000
SSH_TTY => /dev/pts/0
LANG => en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL => ignoredups
SHLVL => 1
CVS_RSH => ssh
LESSOPEN => |/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES => 1
_ => /usr/local/bin/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["TERM"] => xterm-256color
_SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
_SERVER["HISTSIZE"] => 1000
_SERVER["SSH_TTY"] => /dev/pts/0
_SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["HISTCONTROL"] => ignoredups
_SERVER["SHLVL"] => 1
_SERVER["CVS_RSH"] => ssh
_SERVER["LESSOPEN"] => |/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
_SERVER["G_BROKEN_FILENAMES"] => 1
_SERVER["_"] => /usr/local/bin/php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => 
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => 
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] => 
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => 
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => 
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1411615476.0286
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1411615476
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 0
```

Comment: I tried that too, but didn't find any references to suPHP.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what user your script is running as (which in the general case is not necessarily the same as the owner of the file) you can check the output of:

```
$user_info = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
echo $user_info['name'];
```

If this user is *root* run fast and far from your current host.

But it probably isn't.

If the returned user is the same as the file owner (the one you're logging in as over ssh, etc.), `chmod` the config file to `400` - there's no need for it to be world-readable. If it's a different user `chmod 444`.

When you need to modify the file:

1. `chmod u+w your.file` to set the writable bit for the user. *(If you own the file you **can** do this even if the file is read-only.)*
2. Make your modifications.
3. `chmod u-w your.file` to remove the writable bit.

<sub>*(`chmod u+w` is the same as `chmod 600` or `chmod 644`, depending on the beginning permissions, while the `u-w` reverses it.)*</sub>

Comment: +1, also you must use Octal mode (ie, 0444) if doing this via PHP's [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache as web server, most of the times it uses www-data user for writing files but not always.

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

Check the user who's running apache, maybe it is the owner of the folder.

Comment: I checked the owner and group of the public_html folder. The owner is the same user who owns all web files (call it "domainowner"), but the group is literally "nobody". In contrast, all the files within public_html belong to the group "domainowner" (not literally, I mean that the group has the same name as the files owner). I ran the command you suggested and the result was either "nobody" or "root" in most cases (in one row the user was identified as a number). So if I make the folder public_html belong to the group with the same name as the owner instead of "nobody" that will solve it?

Comment: So how is PHP able to write to the file?